# Javascript Problem with Variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I have created a function to showing a title text in a separate div, its wotks perfectly, but a have problems with "title" attribute, so i wonna delete it after tooltipp wenn be displayed. And on mouse ou show it agaiin, but the variable tooltipptext is empty... same one an idea?

```
var tooltipptext;    
$(".infoimg").hover(function(event) {
        tooltipptext = $(this).attr("title");

        showToolTip(event, tooltipptext);
        $(this).attr("title", "");

        return false;       
    });

    $(".infoimg").mouseout(function()   {
        $("#bubble_tooltip").hide();
        $(this).attr("title", tooltipptext);
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? What doesn't work?

Comment: how do you know title is empty?

Comment: $(this).attr("title", tooltipptext); tooltiptext is empty, but it shouldn't be

Comment: also, the .hover function takes two functions as parameters, the first being onmouseover, and the second being onmouseout.  you dont have to have the separate mouseout, just put the function as the second parameter to the .hover call

Comment: becouse if i hover the object again, that contains no text, also i tryed to alert this variable.

Comment: @John how can i do this?

Comment: @Fincha - I already showed how to do this below...and also in a alternative way that may be more appealing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), when passed a single functions runs it on *both* `mouseenter` **and** `mouseleave`, clering the variable because this:

```
tooltipptext = $(this).attr("title");
```

runs again after `$(this).attr("title", "");` ran already.  Instead pass both functions to [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), like this:

```
var tooltipptext;    
$(".infoimg").hover(function() {
    tooltipptext = $(this).attr("title");
    showToolTip(event, tooltipptext);
    $(this).attr("title", "");
}, function()  {
    $("#bubble_tooltip").hide();
    $(this).attr("title", tooltipptext);
});
```

---

Or since you're *never* seeing the title attribute on hover, store it once like this:

```
$(".infoimg").each(function() {
  var title = $(this).attr("title");
  $(this).data('title', title).attr('title','');
}).hover(function() {      
  showToolTip(event, $.data(this, 'title'));
}, function()  {
  $("#bubble_tooltip").hide();
});
```

This has the added benefit of working on any number of images :)